# How to read contents of a directory in linux on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, unix, fs

I am creating an application on nodejs that has to read contents of a folder in the install location. The installer creates the directory 'cert' at the install location.
My code is:

```
const dircert = './cert'
files = fs.readdirSync(dircert)
if (!files.length) {
    ***some code***
  } else {
    files.forEach(file => {
      if (path.extname(file) == '.key') {
        pathkey = path.resolve(dircert, file)
      }

      if (path.extname(file) == '.crt') {
        pathcert = path.resolve(dircert, file)
      }
    })
```

This runs fine in windows but not in Linux. The installer is not able to read the contents. What do I need to change to ensure that it works in both? I am pretty new to linux.
The application is getting installed in ProgramFiles in windows but in /opt/AppName in linux. Please suggest.

Editing to add: So this cert folder is getting created under /opt/AppName/ in linux and under c:/ProgramFiles/company/App Name/ in Windows. While this code runs fine on windows, on linux this code tries to look for cert at root. How do I make sure it looks for the folder at the installed location which is /opt/AppName, and it should work on both the platforms.

Comment: You'll likely have to provide more info about what you're doing and the tools you're using. The above code works for me on Linux when I fix the typos.  (You're missing a closing "}".) What do you mean by "the installer?" Can you describe that? It's probably related to the relative location of where you're looking for files in the first place.

Comment: Have added some more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question how the files are being installed and how the code is being executed. Both of these matter in Linux. You can use the `__dirname` node variable with `path.resolve()` to get the directory of the current module. If `cert` is below the current module, you can use the following code to resolve the location:

```
const path = require('path');
const dircert = path.resolve(__dirname, 'cert');
```

If you're using ES Modules:

```
import path from 'path';
const dircert = path.resolve('cert').
```

Comment: That is the issue, the process is running from /etc/systemd while the cert folder is located where it is getting installed which is different altogether../opt/AppName/. Now when the process starts it looks for cert at root but I need it to look at /opt/AppName/cert. How do I get the path where the installation files are present?

Comment: Does the code in my answer not work? If cert is not below the current module, you can use relative paths e.g. `'../up/cert'`